# Move content between custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I am importing a large amount of content from [Expression Engine](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine), the content in the other Expression Engine is all grouped together. I have created all the custom post types and taxonomies to organize the content better. However, Once I import the content to WordPress, I need to move the content into the newly created post types.

How do I move content from one custom post type to another?

Comment: What is the CMS?

Comment: Expression Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information about post type is stored in wp_posts table in DB in column post_type - either post, page, attachement and other post types you've defined. So i quess you can use some SQL query in your case. Or you can write some script using WP_Query for fetching posts from cerain category (for example), and [wp_update_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) funtion setting post_type argument to desired post type...

Comment: Ah, ok. Thought there was an official way to do this. 

I did find a plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-type-switcher/ which looked like it might do the job. Throws an error on bulk edits. I posted the issue here if anyone can shed any light : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-error-with-bulk-edit?replies=1